# Android, пример реализации MVP

Tags: android, инспекция-кода, mvp

Недавно в разработке, пробую сделать своё приложение согласно MVP. Оно работает как задумано, но в самом коде местами какая - то каша.

Мне кажется я уже близок к просветлению, прошу прокомментировать код, сказать где я перемудрил и ответить на пару конкретных вопросов, которые крутятся вокруг класса **HomeActivity** и его контракта **HomeContract**.

**UPD** Просьба ко всем, если минусите - пишите пожалуйста причину. Спасибо.

О приложении. Сейчас это просто экран с четыремя кнопками:

- Добавить животное в базу данных
- Извлечь животное с `id = 1` из базы данных и показать его название
- Добавить пак животных в базу данных
- Извлечь пак животных с `id = 1` и показать его `title`

Архитектура:

```
-ui
  -home
    -activity
     -HomeActivity
     -HomeContract
     -HomeModel
     -HomePresenter
-model
 -animal
  -Animal
  -AnimalPack
```

Код:

Базовый интерфейс **MvpView**, нужен я так понимаю ради полиформизма.

```
public interface MvpView {
}
```

Наследник от интерфейса выше, **MvpPresenter**, содержит базовые методы для всех презентеров.

```
public interface MvpPresenter<V extends MvpView> {
    void attachView(V mvpView);

    void viewIsReady();

    void detachView();

    void destroy();
}
```

Абстрактный класс **PresenterBase**, я так понял, определяет какие - то базовые вещи для представлений.

```
public abstract class PresenterBase<T extends MvpView> implements MvpPresenter<T> {

    private T view;

    @Override
    public void attachView(T mvpView) {
        view = mvpView;
    }

    @Override
    public void detachView() {
        view = null;
    }

    public T getView() {
        return view;
    }

    protected boolean isViewAttached() {
        return view != null;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {

    }
}
```

Ок, дальше будет менее "абстрактный" код.

Контракт **HomeContract** для целевой активити

```
public interface HomeContract {

    interface View extends MvpView {

        Animal getAnimalById(int id);

        AnimalPack getAnimalPackById(int id);
    }


    interface Presenter extends MvpPresenter<View> {

        void addAnimal();

        void addAnimalPack();

        Animal getAnimalById(int id);

        AnimalPack getAnimalPackById(int id);
    }
}
```

Вот тут первый затык. С презентером вроде понятно - эти его 4 метода я потом переопределю в отдельном классе презентере(будет ниже) и буду обращаться через них к модели. Но вот с вью. По логике вью должна реализовывать `HomeContract.View` - но зачем? В чём вообще их назначение, понять не могу? От них вроде как 0 пользы абсолютно, в следующем коде это будет видно.

Экран **HomeActivity**

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements HomeContract.View {
    private HomeContract.Presenter presenter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        presenter = new HomePresenter(Room.databaseBuilder(this,
                AnimalDatabase.class, AnimalDatabase.DATABASE_NAME)
                .allowMainThreadQueries()
                .fallbackToDestructiveMigration()
                .build());

        presenter.attachView(this);
        presenter.viewIsReady();

        //Добавляем животное по кнопке
        findViewById(R.id.add_animal_button).setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.addAnimal());
        //Достаём животное по кнопке и показываем его название
        findViewById(R.id.show_animal_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        Animal animal = presenter.getAnimalById(1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), animal.getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
        //Добавляем пак животных по кнопке
        findViewById(R.id.add_animal_pack_button).setOnClickListener(v -> presenter.addAnimalPack());
        //Достаём пак животных по кнопке и показываем название пака
        findViewById(R.id.show_animal_pack_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        AnimalPack animalPack = presenter.getAnimalPackById(1);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), animalPack.getPackName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    });
    }

        //Вот эти два метода только мешают. Зачем они?
        @Override
        public Animal getAnimalById(int id) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public AnimalPack getAnimalPackById(int id) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onDestroy() {
            super.onDestroy();
            presenter.detachView();
            presenter.destroy();
    }
}
```

Дальше идёт сам **HomePresenter** который просто передаёт запросы в модель

```
 public class HomePresenter extends PresenterBase<HomeContract.View> implements HomeContract.Presenter {

        private HomeModel model;

        public HomePresenter(AnimalDatabase animalDB) {
            this.model = new HomeModel(animalDB);
        }

        @Override
        public void addAnimal() {
            model.addAnimal();
        }

        @Override
        public void addAnimalPack() {
            model.addAnimalPack();
        }

        @Override
        public Animal getAnimalById(int id) {
            return model.getAnimalById(id);
        }

        @Override
        public AnimalPack getAnimalPackById(int id) {
            return model.getAnimalPackById(id);
        }


        @Override
        public void viewIsReady() {

        }
    }
```

И сама модель **HomeModel**

```
public class HomeModel {
    private AnimalDatabase animalDB;

    HomeModel(AnimalDatabase animalDB) {
        this.animalDB = animalDB;
    }

    void addAnimal() {
        Animal animal = new Animal();
        animal.setName("Тигр");
        animalDB.daoAccess().insertAnimal(animal);
    }

    void addAnimalPack() {
        AnimalPack animalPack = new AnimalPack();
        animalPack.setPackName("Домашние");
        ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        animalPack.setAnimalsId(list);
        animalDB.daoAccess().insertAnimalPack(animalPack);
    }

    Animal getAnimalById(int id) {
        return animalDB.daoAccess().getAnimalById(id);
    }


    AnimalPack getAnimalPackById(int id) {
        return animalDB.daoAccess().getAnimalPackById(id);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> По логике вью должна реализовывать HomeContract.View - но зачем? В чём
>   вообще их назначение, понять не могу?

Это такой же контракт, как и для презентера, но в контракте должна прослеживаться логика отображения информации во вью. Примерно вот так:

```
 interface View extends MvpView {    
        void showAnimalPack(AnimalPack animalPack);
 }
 ...
        //в onCreate
        findViewById(R.id.show_animal_pack_button).setOnClickListener(v -> {
        presenter.setAnimalPackById(1);
    });
```

Потом переопределите метод во вью

```
        @Override
        public void showAnimalPack(AnimalPack animalPack) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), animalPack.getPackName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
```

Потом переопределить метод в презентере

```
    @Override
    public void setAnimalPackById(int id) {
        view.showAnimalPack(model.getAnimalPackById(id));
    }
```

Более практичное объяснение почему мы делаем отдельные методы для отображения - это их переиспользование. Например, у нас паттерн при котором презентер переживает поворот активити, тогда с помощью некоторых манипуляций можно отобразить на новой активити состояние экрана, которое было до ее смерти. Подробнее об этом подходе можно прочитать [тут](https://habr.com/ru/post/276189/) и посмотреть [тут](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8_hbxA4kx50)

Еще такие методы нужны для разделения логики, чтобы легче читался код.

Comment: Теперь я прозрел, благодарю.